# Importar SVG inline de caminho absolute no Next.JS

Tags: react, typescript, svg, eslint, next.js

Eu estou tendo dificuldades em configurar o Next.Js para fazer importações em camino absoluto.

Configurei o **tsconfig.json** usando a **baseUrl** como **"src"** e até funciona, exceto em arquivos SVG inline. Estou usando o **'inline-react-svg'** que funciona se importar caminho relativo mas ignora por completo o caminho absoluto que configurei. E independente se a importação está funcionando ou não o **Eslint** fica dando erro. Segue abaixo o código:

Primeiramente minha estrutura ficou assim:

> - src
>
>   - assets
>   - pages
>   - styles

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

#### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["styled-components", { "ssr": true }],
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

#### .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "standard",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier/standard",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "space-before-function-paren": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"

  }
}
```

### Exemplos:

No arquivo **"./src/pages/_app.tsx"** ele importa o tema (**theme.ts**) e o **GlobalStyles** do Styled Components de forma absoluta conforme o esperado:

#### src/pages/_app.tsx

```
import GlobalStyle from 'styles/global'
import theme from 'styles/theme'
```

Confira que ele não precisou voltar as pastas com **'../'**, mas no meu **index.tsx** ele importa o SVG somente de forma relativa.

#### src/pages/index.tsx

```
import Logo from '../assets/logo.svg' /* assim funciona */
import Logo from 'assets/logo.svg' /* assim não funciona */
```

Mais um porém! Funcionando ou não o Eslint fica enchendo o saco dizendo que o arquivo não existe ou que o tipo não foi definido:

> Cannot find module '../assets/logo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Bem, eu tô usando o **Next.JS 10.0.5** com o **'next-images'**. Creio que isso adiciona a tipagem de todos os arquivos de imagem, inclusive **SVG**. Estou correto? Qual configuração tenho que fazer pra que esse erro na ocorra e que consiga importar de forma absoluta o SVG inline?

Comment: Voce tentou criar um arquivo de tipos personalizados, tipo um arquivo `svgImage.d.ts` por exempo, e adiociona-lo no `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Não, pq instalei o 'next-images', ele cria (ou acredito que crie) os tipos para arquivos de imagens, incluso SVG. E estou iniciando em Typescript, ainda não "pesquei" esse lance de tipificação, que pra mim era só mesmo o tipo de dado: array, string, number, etc... Era acostumado com "prop-types" no CRA.

Answer (score 0):

> Funcionando ou não o Eslint fica enchendo o saco dizendo que o arquivo não existe ou que o tipo não foi definido

Posso estar enganado, mas pelo que vi na documentacão, creio `next-images` não cria os tipos para imagens. Neste caso em específico, você pode tentar criar os próprios tipos para as imagens `.svg` e ver se resolve o problema.

Crie um arquivo chamado de `svg.d.ts` na raiz do projeto e adicione o código:

```js
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

e no seu `tsconfig.json` adicione o arquivo de tipo `svg.d.ts`:

```
"include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "svg.d.ts"
  ],
```

Agora sobre a importacão absoluta, pode usar os [alias](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) para importacão. Válido para as versões Next.js 9.4 e superiores.

No seu `tsconfig.json` adicione (Já sabendo que `"baseUrl": "./src",` e os `assets` dentro desta pasta):

```
"paths": {
      "@/assets/*": ["assets/*"]
    }
```

Ele resolve qualquer importacão que comece com `@/assets` para a pastas `assets` dentro de `src`. Na hora de importar, escreva:

```
import Logo from '@/assets/logo.svg'
```

Não tenho certeza se resolve todos os problemas, mas acho que vale a pena você testar :).

Comment: A questão do Eslint, funcionou em partes. Ele reclamou no "any" na segunda linha do "svg.d.ts" que você sugeriu pro pôr na raíz, daí dei uma pesquisada e substituí por "React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>". Só assim ele parou de incomodar, mas a importação absoluta não funciona nem depois de restartar a aplicação.

Comment: Qual sua versao do nextjs? Mais tarde posso dar uma revisada nisso ai.

Comment: A versão mais atual até o momento: 10.0.5